# Old logo is still used in iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

(I reported this for the RPi site when it graduated, and now you've done it again for Blender!)

The old logo is still used in the iOS app for the communities sidebar and the Profile > All *x* communities page:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the low-res picture, I had to edit It and submit on my iPad.

Comment: Note that the meta site logo is working properly (strange)

Comment: The old logo is appearing in chat too http://i.imgur.com/jgrmYQW.png

Comment: @Wanda That was one of the things I reported on RPi too....

Comment: This now appears to be fixed.

Comment: The chat graphics dont seem to have been dealt with, I tried a hard refresh, perhaps it's separate to the ios app issues.

Comment: @Wanda Make a new question tagged design and bug, that would probably bring more visibility

Comment: [The old logo is still in used in the chat context menu](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1039/the-old-logo-is-still-in-used-in-the-chat-context-menu)